# CSS Fixed width container with child div auto expand

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a simple page which has fixed width container, then inside the container a div which overflows to fill the browsers width. In the fiddle i am aiming to get the `.content <div>` to expand when the browser is resized width ways.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z59tb/2/)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Z59tb/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z59tb/3/), is this what you're after?...alternatively- have a look at [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/R6fFt/), which is an alternative take based on your question.

CSS

```
body {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    height: 150px;
    background: #FFE680;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 0 100px;
    background-color: #DD0022;
}

.footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: #BFF08E;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks that is close but instead of all the divs expanding i would just like the middle red one to expand the rest stay fixed.

Comment: Hi thanks, sorry just saw the second one. Thats perfect! Thanks for your help.